# Error calling function second time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a function which works just fine the first if I call it just once, but when I call it repeatedly within a for loop, I get the following error:

TypeError: getNamedRange is not a function, it is string.

Doing a search on this error gives me a clue that this is a javascript error, not a Google Apps Script error.  I haven't worked much with javascript, but I suspect it may have something to do with how I return the value from the function.

This is the code which calls the function:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var baseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Base");

var catCol = 9;
var riskAreaColumn = 10;

var numRows = baseSheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();

// I am not using this var, should I be?
var data = baseSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

var cell;
var rangeName;
var range;
var rule;

for(var i=2; i<numRows; i++){

  cell = baseSheet.getRange(i, riskAreaColumn);

  rangeName = getNamedRange("CategoryRiskRange",baseSheet.getRange(i, catCol).getValue());

  range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(rangeName);

  rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule);

  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

This is the function being called:

```
function getNamedRange(categoryRange, category) {

var categoryList = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName(categoryRange).getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < categoryList.length; i++) {

  if (categoryList[i][0] == category) {
    getNamedRange = categoryList[i][1];
    return getNamedRange;
  }
}
}
```

The first time through the for loop works, the second time gives me the aforementioned error.  Thank you for reading this, I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are overwriting the function definition here:

```
getNamedRange = categoryList[i][1];
```

this will work:

```
 if (categoryList[i][0] == category) {
    return categoryList[i][1];
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript doesn't interpret things until it gets to them, and is very happy to redefine things when you tell it to.

The first time through, it sees

```
function getNamedRange(categoryRange, category)
```

and says "oh, a function! Cool!" But in that function, you have the line

```
getNamedRange = categoryList[i][1];
```

and it says "Oh, so getNamedRange is something else now. Okay, I'm fine with that."

Rename your variable, and you should be fine.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation of the logic behind the javascript.  Do other languages do the same?  I think I borrowed the syntax from some other language, or maybe I just made it up?  Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Java and C++ would complain about the reassignment*, because they are what's called "strongly typed". Javascript and Python will happily let you do what you did. Just depends on the language.


*Actually, because you would have to declare getNamedRange as a String inside the function in C++ or Java, you can get away with the reassignment because the compiler would know which getNamedRange you're referring to by where you're calling it and how you're referring to it. But you couldn't just do getNamedRange = categoryList[i][1]; without specifically declaring the variable.